# Why does angular-cli use a different version of tsc

Tags: angular, typescript, npm

My globally installed is:

```
root@d5ce58967dc0:~# tsc --version
Version 2.6.2
```

whereas, the installed that got pulled in when creating a new angular project is:

```
root@d5ce58967dc0:~/ng5webapp# node_modules/.bin/tsc --version
Version 2.5.3
```

Can't the globally installed `tsc` automatically be the same version that gets installed also?

Comment: Why do you have `tsc` installed globally?

Comment: I am using Docker, and i have many prepared docker images based from `node:latest` base image. In some image, I have a global `tsc` and in others i don't have. So i tried many permutations of this and that, and observing how `ng` behaves to this and that. For example, the global `ng` version is also not the same version pulled in into the project. If why this is so is an arbitrary decision or is there a reason, just want to know why.

Comment: You can just install `tsc` as a dependency in npm and then use it in your `scripts` in `package.json`.